# Let $h(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x\neq0$,$h(0)=0$. Show that $h^{(n)}(0)=0 \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, polynomials, induction

Let $h(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ for $x\neq0$ , $h(0)=0$. Show that $h^{(n)}(0)=0$ 
      $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

Conclude that
the remainder term in Taylor’s Theorem for $x_0\neq 0$ does not converge to zero as $n \to \infty$ for $x\neq0$.

[Hint: By L’Hospital’s Rule, $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{h(x)}{x^k}=0$$ for any $k \in N$ ]

Here is what I know:

$$h'(0)=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x}=\lim_{y\to\infty} \frac{e^{-y^2}}{\frac{1}{y}}=\lim_{y\to\infty} \frac{y}{e^{y^2}}$$
By L'Hospital's,
$$\lim_{y\to\infty} \frac{y}{e^{y^2}}=\lim_{y\to\infty} \frac{1}{2ye^{y^2}}=0$$
Then,

$h'(x)=\frac{2}{x^3}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ for $x\neq0$ and $h'(x)=0$ for $x=0$

Now,
$$h''(0)=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\frac{2}{x^3}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{2}{x^4}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

I know that $h''(x)={\frac{4}{x^6}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}-{\frac{6}{x^4}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}$,

But I am having trouble finding $h''(x)$ for when $x=0$

Also, is this the best way to show that $h^{(n)}(0)=0$ 
      $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ or is there a simpler method? Thank you!

Comment: Notice that $h'(x)=\frac{2h(x)}{x^3}$. This should simplify your working.

Answer (score 1):

So, following Karn, we can outline a proof as follows.

Lemma 1.  If $p$ is a polynomial, then the derivative of $p(1/x)e^{-1/x^2}$ is of the form $q(1/x)e^{-1/x^2}$ for some other polynomial.

Lemma 2.  If $p$ is a polynomial, then $\lim_{x \to 0} p(1/x)e^{-1/x^2} = 0$.

Use the Lemma 1, and induction, to show that every $h^{(n)}(x)$ is of the form $p(1/x)e^{-1/x^2}$.  And Lemma 2 to show all these go to zero at $x=0$.

The advantage of this method is that you do not have to compute the exact polynomials involved.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
h(x) &= e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} \\
\lim_{x \to 0}h(x) &= 0 \\
h'(x) &= \frac{2e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x^3} = \frac{2h(x)}{x^3} \\
h''(x) &=  \frac{2x^3h'(x)-6x^2h(x)}{x^3}=2h'(x)-\frac{6h(x)}{x} \\
h^{(3)}(x) &=  2h''(x)-\frac{6xh'(x)-6h(x)}{x} =2h''(x)-6h'(x)-\frac{6h(x)}{x}\\
h^{(4)}(x) &=2h^{(3)}(x)-6h^{(2)}(x)-6h'(x)-\frac{6h(x)}{x}\\
&\vdots\\
h^{(n)}(x)&=2h^{(n-1)}-6\left(h^{(n-2)}(x)+h^{(n-3)}(x)+h^{(n-4)}(x)+\ldots +h'(x) \right) - \frac{6h(x)}{x}&
\end{align}

Since we know that $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{h(x)}{x^k}=0$$
for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Therefore, for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $h^{(m)}(0)=0$ if $h^{(r)}=0$ for all $r \in \mathbb{N}$, $ r <m$.

Hence $$h'(0)=0 \implies h''(0)=0 \implies h^{(3)}(0)=0 \implies h^{(4)}(0)=0 \implies \cdots \implies h^{(n)}(0)=0$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

---

(I can't do the Taylor series part yet because I haven't learnt it. I am still sitting for A Level right now.)

Answer (score 0):

> Let prove by induction that for $n>0$ 
>   $$h^{(n)} (x)= P_{2n+1}(\frac1x)e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$$
>   where $P_{2n+1}$ is a polynomial of degree, $2n+1$

$$h'(x) = \frac{2e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x^3}= P_{3}(\frac1x)e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

Assume that $$h^{(n)} (x)= P_{2n+1}(\frac1x)e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

then, $$h^{(n+1)} (x)= P_{3}(\frac1x)P_{2n+1}(\frac1x)e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} -\frac{1}{x^2}P'_{2n+1}(\frac1x)e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\equiv P_{2n+3}(\frac1x)e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

Since, $$ P_{3}(\frac1x)P_{2n+1}(\frac1x)$$ is of degree $2n+3.$

Now we have,

> **Lemma:** for all $m\ge 0$ $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^m}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=0$$

Indeed, 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^m}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=\lim_{h\to \pm\infty} h^m e^{-h^2} = \lim_{h\to \pm\infty} \left(h^2 e^{-h^2/m}\right)^{m/2} \\= \left(m\right)^{m/2}\lim_{h\to \pm\infty} \left(\frac{h^2}{m} e^{-h^2/m}\right)^{m/2}=\left(m\right)^{m/2}\lim_{u\to \infty} \left(u e^{-u}\right)^{m/2} = 0$$

From this you get, that by induction that, 
$$h^{(n)}(0) = \frac{h^{(n-1)}(x)}{x} = \frac{1}{x}P_{2n-1}(\frac1x)e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} =0.$$

Assuming that it is already true for $h^{(n-1)}.$